# Has a Navision 3.0 (Released in 2001) any API?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, erp, navision

I need to integrate WEB application with Navision 3.0. 
How can i do this? Has a navision 3.0 some integration services like SOAP, RPC?
Or I can do this only used shared database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only whay to do this in this old navision version is to use directly the database.

Verify that the SQL sentences that you use block the tables that you are using to keep database consistence.

Answer (score 1):

All Windows versions of Navision starting from the 1.x Financials versions are COM controllers. So you can always write a COM server (or a .NET InterOp Assembly with a COM Callable wrapper CCW) and use that one from Navision.